# Gulp task runs to minify CSS but no CSS file is created?

Tags: gulp, gulp-concat

I'm new with Gulp but I've followed along with an online course. Now I'm trying to implement it into a MVC template project so I will have a starting point for projects going forward.

Ultimately I would like to get Gulp to compile and minify some LESS files but right now I'm just taking small steps. So, I'm trying to get Gulp to concatinate and minify my CSS files.

I've installed Node and Gulp both globally and locally. I've also installed both gulp-concat and gulp-minify-css into the project. I've setup my gulpfile.js as seen below. When I run the Task, I don't get an error but my site.min.css isn't created either. What I excpect to see is the Bootstrap.css and Site.css combined, minified, and placed in the Content folder.

I've looked this over several times but I'm not seeing why this isn't working.

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var uglify = require('gulp-uglify');
var concat = require('gulp-concat');
var minifyCss = require('gulp-minify-css');

//Less plugins
var less = require('gulp-less');


//File paths
var SCRIPTS_PATH = 'Scripts/**/*.js';
var LESS_PATH = 'Content/**/*.less';
var CSS_PATH = 'Content';


//Styles
gulp.task('styles', function () {
    return gulp.src(CSS_PATH)
        .pipe(concat('site.min.css'))
        .pipe(minifyCss())
        .pipe(gulp.dest(CSS_PATH));
})

//Scripts
gulp.task('scripts', function () {
    console.log('starting scripts task')

    return gulp.src(SCRIPTS_PATH)
        .pipe(uglify())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('Scripts/app/app.js'));
})
```

[image]

Comment: have you tried this > `var CSS_PATH = 'Content/**/*.css'`?

Comment: Cool. That seems to have worked. Initially I got an error but it had to do with something in the scripts task. I don't need that at the moment so I commented that out. I didn't realized I had to specify the *.css to pick up.